# How to run a Common Apache Daemon Window Service on interval of 2 hours automatically

Tags: java, batch-file, apache-commons

I have installed a Windows Service through [Common Apache Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) Service . My Installation batch file's code is as

```
@echo off

setlocal

rem The service names (make sure they does not clash with an existing service)
rem set SERVICE_JVM=MyService
set SERVICE_JAVA=MyService

rem my location
set MYPATH=C:\MyService\src\classes

rem location of Prunsrv
set PATH_PRUNSRV=C:\MyService\src\bin
set PR_LOGPATH=C:\MyService\logs
rem location of jarfile
set PATH_JAR=%MYPATH%

rem Allow prunsrv to be overridden
if "%PRUNSRV%" == "" set PRUNSRV=%PATH_PRUNSRV%\MyService.exe

rem Install the 2 services

echo Installing %SERVICE_JVM%
%PRUNSRV% //DS//%SERVICE_JVM%
%PRUNSRV% //IS//%SERVICE_JVM%

echo Setting the parameters for %SERVICE_JAVA%
%PRUNSRV% //US//%SERVICE_JVM% --Startup=auto --Jvm=auto --StdOutput auto --StdError auto ^
--Classpath=%PATH_JAR%\MyService.jar ^
--StartMode=jvm --StartClass=Webmuch.MyService --StartMethod=main --StartParams=start ^
--StopMode=jvm  --StopClass=Webmuch.MyService  --StopMethod=main --StopParams=stop

echo Installation of %SERVICE_JAVA% is complete

echo Installing %SERVICE_JAVA%
%PRUNSRV% //DS//%SERVICE_JAVA%
%PRUNSRV% //IS//%SERVICE_JAVA%

echo Setting the parameters for %SERVICE_JAVA%
%PRUNSRV% //US//%SERVICE_JAVA% --Startup=auto --Jvm=auto --StdOutput auto --StdError auto ^
--Classpath=%PATH_JAR%\MyService.jar ^
--StartMode=jvm --StartClass=Webmuch.MyService --StartMethod=main --StartParams=start ^
--StopMode=jvm  --StopClass=Webmuch.MyService  --StopMethod=main --StopParams=stop

%PRUNSRV% //TS//%SERVICE_JAVA%

echo Installation of %SERVICE_JAVA% is complete
echo Finished
```

When I run this batch file in shell command 
  as

> InstallService.bat

my service is installed and running and also when ever i run my service as

> MyService.exe //TS//MyService

It is working fine .

**But My requirement is to run this service on interval of every 2 hours automatically when  personal system machine starts .**

I do't know from where i can make configuration regarding this ?

If Any have idea please help me .

Thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 hours, you can:

```
:loop

rem call your service
timeout 7200
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot [COO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4179928/coo) It works fine while i run my batch file from command prompt shell but my service is not running while my system is restarted and also it is not being repeated after given time interval .

Comment: Any way Thanks a lot to you and i have resolved my problem to putting short cut of my service in Startup and your solution helped me a lot of ,Again Thanks a lot ..